# NameError on accessing ancestor constants when using Class.new?

Tags: ruby, nameerror

To my current knowledge Ruby classes defined with `Class.new` should not differ from classes created with the `class` keyword. Then why do following classes B and C behave differently?

```ruby
class A
  TEST = 'A'   
  def test
    TEST
  end   
end

class B < A
 def test
  TEST
 end    
end

C = Class.new(A) {        
 def test
  TEST
 end    
}

puts 'A: ' + A.new.test # => "A: A"
puts 'B: ' + B.new.test # => "B: A"
puts 'C: ' + C.new.test # => uninitialized constant TEST (NameError)
```

Tested with ruby 1.9.3p327 and ruby 1.8.7p358.

Comment: I'm not getting the error with ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i386-darwin9.8.0].  But Ruby's scoping of constants can be quite subtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause you a using a block for defining `C` class, and the scope of that block is the `main` instead of `A`

to have it work:

```
C = Class.new(A)

def C.test
  TEST
end
```

or:

```
class << C
    def test
      TEST
    end    
end
```

Comment: This was quick. Thanks, slivu!